# Navigation button User location

Tags: swift, location, mapkit

What kind of code do I need to make my bar button locate and zoom to the user's location like in Google maps? I tried the following:

```
if Navigationbutton != nil {
    Navigationbutton.target = MKMapView()
    Navigationbutton.action = CLLocationCoordinate2D (latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem! https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserTrackingBarButtonItemClassRef/